# LINQ (or something else) to compare a pair of values from two lists (in any order)?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, comparison, ienumerable

Basically, I have two `IEnumerable<FooClass>`s where each FooClass instance contains 2 properties: FirstName, LastName.

The instances on each of the enumerables is **NOT** the same. Instead, I need to check against the properties on each of the instances. I'm not sure of the most efficient way to do this, but basically I need to make sure that both lists contain similar data (not the same instance, but the same values on the properties). I don't have access to the FooClass itself to modify it.

---

I should say that the FooClass is a type of Attribute class, which has access to the [Attribute.Match()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.match.aspx) method, so I don't need to check each properties individually.

---

Based on the comments, I've updated the question to be more specific and changed it slightly... This is what I have so far:

```
public void Foo()
{
        var info = typeof(MyClass);
        var attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FooAttribute), false) as IEnumerable<FooAttribute>;

        var validateAttributeList = new Collection<FooAttribute>
            {
                new FooAttribute(typeof(int), typeof(double));
                new FooAttribute(typeof(int), typeof(single));
            };

        //Make sure that the each item in validateAttributeList is contained in
        //the attributes list (additional items in the attributes list don't matter).
        //I know I can use the Attribute.Match(obj) to compare.
}
```

Comment: If an item is in List A and not in List B, do you want to add it to List B, or just report that the lists don't contain the same information?

Comment: Just report that they don't contain the same information.

Comment: Your question is very unclear at the moment. Sample data would really, really help. (Also, does FooClass override Equals/GetHashCode?) Can there be repeats, and if so what do they mean? (Do the repeat numbers need to be the same in the two lists)?

Comment: The elements in a single list are unique ? If not, consider these 2 lists: [A,A,B] and [B,B,A] are they equal to you or not ? (just to know if set operation is an option...)

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question with code and figured out exactly what I want and how to state it... I hope.

Comment: Can you answer me too please?Is it certain that they have the same number of FooClass in them?I mean the Count of lists are they equal?

Comment: Oh, sorry, no... they are not certain to be equal. The attributes list could have 100s... I only care that it contains AT LEAST those 2 items.

Comment: that wasn't what i meant, never mind thanks for  the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in this way:

**Define a custom** `IEqualityComparer<FooAttribute>` :

```
class FooAttributeComparer : IEqualityComparer<FooAttribute>
{
    public bool Equals(FooAttribute x, FooAttribute y)
    {
        return x.Match(y);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(FooAttribute obj)
    {
        return 0;
        // This makes lookups complexity O(n) but it could be reasonable for small lists 
        // or if you're not sure about GetHashCode() implementation to do.
        // If you want more speed you could return e.g. :
        // return obj.Field1.GetHashCode() ^ (17 * obj.Field2.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

**Define an extension method to compare lists in any order and having the same number of equal elements:**

```
public static bool ListContentIsEqualInAnyOrder<T>(
this IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    var lookup1 = list1.ToLookup(x => x, comparer);
    var lookup2 = list2.ToLookup(x => x, comparer);
    if (lookup1.Count != lookup2.Count)
        return false;
    return lookup1.All(el1 => lookup2.Contains(el1.Key) && 
            lookup2[el1.Key].Count() == el1.Count());
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<FooAttribute> attrs = new List<FooAttribute>
    {
        new FooAttribute(typeof(int), typeof(double)),
        new FooAttribute(typeof(int), typeof(double)),
        new FooAttribute(typeof(bool), typeof(float)),
        new FooAttribute(typeof(uint), typeof(string)),
    };
    List<FooAttribute> attrs2 = new List<FooAttribute>
    {
        new FooAttribute(typeof(uint), typeof(string)),
        new FooAttribute(typeof(int), typeof(double)),
        new FooAttribute(typeof(int), typeof(double)),
        new FooAttribute(typeof(bool), typeof(float)),
    };

    // this returns true
    var listEqual1 = attrs.ListContentIsEqualInAnyOrder(attrs2, new FooAttributeComparer());

    // this returns false
    attrs2.RemoveAt(1);
    var listEqual2 = attrs.ListContentIsEqualInAnyOrder(attrs2, new FooAttributeComparer());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Enumerable.SequenceEqual` will tell you if the two sequences are identical.

If `FooClass` has an overridden `Equals` method that compares the `FirstName` and `LastName`, then you should be able to write:

```
bool equal = List1.SequenceEqual(List2);
```

If `FooClass` doesn't have an overridden `Equals` method, then you need to create an `IEqualityComparer<FooClass>`:

```
class FooComparer: IEqualityComparer<FooClass>
{
    public bool Equals(FooClass f1, FooClass f2)
    {
        return (f1.FirstName == f2.FirstName) && (f1.LastName == f2.LastName);
    }
    public int GetHashCode()
    {
        return FirstName.GetHashCode() ^ LastName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and then you write:

```
var comparer = new FooComparer();
bool identical = List1.SequenceEqual(List2, comparer);
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question a bit more to be less vague... not sure if this answer still applies.

Comment: @m-y: The answer still applies, although you'll have to change the equality comparer so that it compares the correct fields in your `FooAttribute` class. Other than that, the idea is still the same: use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`.

Comment: Can I use the built in Attribute.Match() function in place of the EqualityComparer though?

Comment: @m-y: I don't know enough about `Attribute.Match` to say.

Comment: @m-y: But SequenceEqual() returns true only if the order is the same, and your question states "in any order"...

Comment: @digEmAll, so I got a false positive because my lists happen to be in the same order? Dang.

Comment: @m-y: yes :) I have just provided a solution in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

1. The lists both fit in memory and are unsorted
2. Case doesn't matter
3. Names don't contain the character "!"
4. Names do not contain duplicates:

then

```
var setA = new HashSet<String>(
    firstEnumerable.Select(i => i.FirstName.ToUpper() + "!" + i.LastName.ToUpper()));
var setB = new HashSet<String>(
    secondEnumerable.Select(i => i.FirstName.ToUpper() + "!" + i.LastName.ToUpper()));
return setA.SetEquals(setB);
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question a bit more to be less vague... not sure if this answer still applies.